# ¿Cómo puedo poner un botón debajo de cada imagen que esta en un scroll horizontal y en la siguiente estructura?

Tags: html5

¿Cómo puedo poner un botón debajo de cada imagen, que esta en un scroll horizontal y en la siguiente estructura?

```
<style>
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}


.contenedor_completo_catalogo {
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.20);
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: auto;
overflow: hidden;
overflow-y: auto;
overflow-x: scroll;
scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
padding-right: 34px;
}

.contenedor_completo_catalogo::-webkit-scrollbar {
display: none;
}

.contenedor_completo_catalogo {
-webkit-overflow-style: none;
-moz-overflow-style: none;
-ms-overflow-style: none;
-o-overflow-style: none;
scrollbar-width: none;
}

.imagen_contenedor {
margin: auto;
display: flex;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: relative;
}

.imagen_contenedor img {
object-fit: cover;
max-width: 100%;
height: 100%;
scroll-snap-align: center;
/*opacity: 0.5;*/
}   
</style>


<div class='contenedor_completo_catalogo'>
<section class='imagen_contenedor'>
<img src='img/imagen1.jpg'>  
<a href"" class='boton'>boton1</a>
<img src='img/imagen2.jpg'>  
<a href"" class='boton'>boton2</a>
<img src='img/imagen3.jpg'>  
<a href"" class='boton'>boton3</a>
<img src='img/imagen4.jpg'>  
<a href"" class='boton'>boton4</a>
</section>  
</div>
```